# Why did GHC notice me about missing libraries while it actually had been installed?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, parsec

I am learn `parsec`, however, when I run below code in my **Ubuntu 14.04** laptop with `ghc 7.10.1`:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
```

I got such error message

```
fac.hs:2:8:
    Could not find module ‘Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the "dyn" libraries for package ‘parsec-3.1.9@parse_CtL7rSgjxYR5wAnuCckBL7’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

However, I did have `parsec` installed in `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/parsec/3.1.9`, then why would `ghc` notify me that it couldn't find the module?

And what does the "dyn libraries" mean?

Comment: Can you run `ghc-pkg list` and show the output?

Comment: `~/.cabal/packages/` is just a cache of downloaded tarballs, packages aren't "installed" there. For example parsec might be there as a side effect of having installed it with a different version of ghc.

Comment: "dyn libraries" means dynamic (i.e. shared) libraries. cabal compiles libraries in three main flavours: default (i.e. statically linked), profiling and dynamic. It seems that the whatever procedure you used to install GHC 7.10.1 (instead of the quite old 7.6.3 Ubuntu 14.04 provides) also configured it to use dynamic libraries, but cabal is not configured in the same way.